# How do I save a jsreport render to file with nodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsreport

I am new to node.js and jsreport, but what I am attempting to do is create a pdf in memory using node.js and then saving it to disk.  I need this to be stand-along as it will be running as an AWS Lambda function.

```
var fs = require('fs');
require("jsreport").render("<h1>Hi there!</h1>").then(function(out) {
    //pipe pdf with "Hi there!"
    fs.writeFile('C:\\helloworld.pdf', out, function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('Hello World > helloworld.txt');
    });
fs.close();
    console.log("The End");
});
```

Although this runs the output pdf will not open in Adobe Reader so I assume the file output is not a valid PDF.

this requires npm install jsreport

Comment: fyi `.writeFile` is async.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I gather from the jsreport website (although I haven't been able to verify, as none of the examples on their website work for me), it looks like `out` isn't rendered (PDF) data, but an object that contains—amongst other things—a stream.

Which leads me to believe that this might work:

```
require("jsreport").render("<h1>Hi there!</h1>").then(function(out) {
  out.result.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('c:\\helloworld.pdf'));
});
```